# How to iterate through the element attribute value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate through element attribute value and get the following values: 
1. Email 
2. Department

The Element Attribute value looks like:

```
<div id="divEntityData">
<div data="

<ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">abc@gmail.com</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">IT</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>


<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">AccountName</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">PrincipalType</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">User</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

</ArrayOfDictionaryEntry>
">
</div>
</div>
```

So far i tried like this but not got proper output:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = $("#divEntityData").find("div").attr("data");
//console.log();
for (var i=0; i<$(d).length; i++) {
    console.log($(d)[i]);
}
});
```

Comment: You're going to have a frustrating time on this if you use double quotes like that within your `data` attribute; your present value is only `<ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsd=` due to the presence of a terminating quote.

Comment: but i can't change that attribute it gets dynamically  generated.

Comment: No need, just encapsulate it in single quotes rather than double quotes - since you never use those in the value, it will then work.

Comment: sry i didn't get u. you mean this values xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" quotes shud be in single quotes

Comment: @Light - Serlite meant change your html to <div data='your_xml_here'></div>

Comment: Yeah. If you're still not sure what is meant by that, PeterKA did silently make this correction in their answer.

Comment: Thnks Serlite for your help but the whole div element dynamically gets generated in sharepoint page layout page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do XML DOM parsing.

```
var txt = $("#divEntityData").find("div").attr("data");
var parser;
var xmlDoc;
if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
}
```

Now, you can perform operations on xmlDoc to get data.

For e.g.

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DictionaryEntry")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue // Gives you Email
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DictionaryEntry")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue // Gives you abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Yes you need to loop through the xmlDoc. For your reference, I have updated my answer with an example as well.

Comment: i am getting null value in console "console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DictionaryEntry")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue);"

Comment: @Light See my comment, this is likely due to a problem with how you've written your attribute value.

Comment: The above should have worked. You can try this -  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DictionaryEntry")[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Changing the jquery though provides some results:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = $("ArrayOfDictionaryEntry").find("DictionaryEntry");
    d.each(function(){
        var key=$(this).find('Key').text();
        var val=$(this).find('Value').text();
        console.log(key+' '+val);
    });
for (var i=0; i<$(d).length; i++) {
    console.log($(d)[i]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var xml = $.parseXML( $('#divEntityData > div[data-xml]').data('xml') );
var xObj = {};
$(xml).find('DictionaryEntry').each(function(i,v) {
  xObj[ $(v).find('Key').text() ] = $(v).find('Value').text();
});
console.log( xObj );
console.log( xObj.Department );
console.log( xObj.Email );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divEntityData">
<div data-xml='

<ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">abc@gmail.com</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">IT</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>


<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">AccountName</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">abc</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">PrincipalType</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">User</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>

</ArrayOfDictionaryEntry>
'>
</div>
</div>
```